# Add parent terms (metadata) automatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

People usually don't add the parent tag to managed metadata - can it be added automatically for them?

**Here is my structure:**

- Sector

  - Finance

    - Wells Fargo
  - Healthcare

    - Health company

If someone tags 'Wells Fargo', it's not picked up by search refiner when refined by Finance tag as it's not tagged Finance. Can tag 'Finance' be added automatically if someone tags its child, Wells Fargo?

I had a look into workflows and Azure logic but neither seems to offer it.